# WordPress and user security

Tags: database, security

When we talk about Information Security, many things come into mind and people tend to use CMS to be clear on security as CMS people do the job for you, in terms on hashing passwords, encryption etc. But how foolproof can it be? Like WordPress. I have a project in which a lot of financial information of user will be stored and i opted out for WordPress, but i doubt my selection as it's open source. But when i see websites like ebay, cnn and other sites build onto it, i am little confident. But really, is WordPress really best CMS out there to create something complex which involve a lot of security, like why people use oracle financials? Am i good to use wordpress?

Comment: [This](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/192553/31545) should be related. Also note, each country has its own requirements regarding safegaurding personal info. I personally think this is the wrong stack to ask such a valuable question as none of us are professional law people, and one misstep **can** land you in jail if such info leaks out. Best is, study and make sure you understand the minimum and when in doubt, phone a laywer and a security expert

Comment: There was a recent [discussion](http://www.quora.com/I-am-powering-a-banks-website-using-WordPress-What-security-measures-should-I-take) on Quora about a banking site using WordPress and Matt Mullenweg responded [here](http://ma.tt/2015/04/a-bank-website-on-wordpress/).